# Programmatically set active-menuitem of PrimeFaces responsive themes

Tags: java, primefaces, themes

We're using one of the new responsive themes of PrimeFaces 8 ([Mirage](https://www.primefaces.org/mirage/dashboard.xhtml) if that matters) I've implemented a dynamic menu to create the menu of my page. Depending on several parameters, the landing page can be different. Example:
Suppose there's a communications environment in which the menu items are

- Documents (opens by default)
- E-mail
- Pictures

When arriving in the communications environment, the application checks whether there are new e-mails. If so, the user won't arrive on the "Documents" page but on the "E-mails" page.

The theme uses cookies to restore the menu state based on what the user has chosen previously. So suppose last time (s)he has chosen "Pictures", the result now is that the menu item "Pictures" is marked as `active-menuitem` but the displayed page is "E-mail".

I was already able to clear the cookies so that no menu item is active, but now I'm trying to activate the correct menu item. I got most successful by calling

```
PF('sidebarMenu').activate($('.custom-active-menuitem').closest('li'));
PF('sidebarMenu').activate($('.custom-active-menuitem').closest('ul').closest('li'));
```

but since the page is rebuild using ajax, this only works once . Using the build-in `.active-menuitem` doesn't work so that's why I introduced `.custom-active-menuitem` that I set in Java code:

```
DefaultMenuItem.builder()
               .value("E-mail")
               .icon("fa fa-letter")
               .command("#{communicationBean.openEmailPage()}")
               .styleClass("custom-active-menuitem") // or something else to mark this item active
               .process("@this")
               .update(":page");
```

So now I'm puzzled. Can someone please get me in the correct direction? How can I make the theme show the menu item I choose as active one?

Comment: I definitely see your problem. Hopefully someone on the Mirage forum will answer your question from PrimeTek.  Unfortunalely those sidebar menus are custom components built for the Layout specifically and not a core PF component.